# CSS reflecting in masterpage not in child pages for table

Tags: html, asp.net, css, formatting

My login page code looks like this. The style for the table is working perfectly when I use internal style sheet in the header.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css"> 
     table {
    background: #FF66FF;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue" , "Lucida Grande" , "Segoe UI" , Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
    width: 100%;
}

 </style>
</asp:Content>
```

[image: InternalCSS]

But when I copy paste the same thing in the external style sheet, it does not format my table!

[image: ExternalCSS]

Where is it getting lost?What seems to be the problem?

Validation control is getting the formatting from the same css page

Comment: share your rendered HTML output for child page

Comment: @Sunny Edited my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! One page reload fixed it. What multiple builds didn't do, a simple refresh did! Nothing was wrong with the code. Must have been some cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine here with the given rendered HTML and style:

```
<table id="greentable" >
    <tr>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td class="style1"> <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtUserName" type="text" id="MainContent_txtUserName" /> 
            <span id="MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="display:none;"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

see the demo:

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/Q79aH/

Check if the styles.css file path is correct and is being rendered correctly.

Comment: I added css for other controls on that page. They are working fine. Still not able to format my tables.

Comment: well, that's another question :)

Comment: Why? That was my original question!

Comment: so the main problem remains, right? Share your complete Rendered HTML code. Better you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net and share the link in your question. Don't forget adding the CSS.

Comment: I tried jsfiddle. It does not recognize the asp elements in the html.
When I inserted this in the header as an internal style sheet, it works! 
    <style type="text/css"> 
`table {
    background: #FF66FF;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue" , "Lucida Grande" , "Segoe UI" , Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
    width: 100%;
}
 </style>`

And like I said, the validation summary in this page is pulling the formatting from the same sheet. There is something I am missing!

Comment: @divinediu no prob... share the complete output in your question in separate at bottom.